# Salesforce DataTable issue with timeZone of datetime field

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, lightning-datatable, timezone

Issue I am facing is I am querying a list of data. When I am displaying that data in dataTable, datable is showing date time field based on machine this code is running, not on timeZone assigned to user in salesforce. Like my Local is india/kolkata and Salesforce org user is in America/Los Angeles. So time displayed is india/kolkata not America/Los Angeles.

Here is my sample code

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class TestAccount extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    col = this.columns = [{
        label: 'Name', 
        fieldName: 'Name', 
        type: 'text', 
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        sortable : true
    },{
        label: 'CreatedDate', 
        fieldName: 'CreatedDate', 
        type: 'date', 
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        typeAttributes:{
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }
    }];
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '0012D00000WYFgRQAX', fields: ['Account.Name','Account.CreatedDate']})
    getData({error,data}){
        if(data){
            this.data.push({Id:data.id, Name : data.fields.Name.value, CreatedDate : data.fields.CreatedDate.value});
        }
    }
}
```

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable key-field="id" resize-column-disabled hide-checkbox-column data={data} columns={col} 
    ></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

I have written above example to simplify code. I am actually doing an soql query to get records. This "data.fields.CreatedDate.value" is equal to value we get from soql. (Thats why I didn't used  "data.fields.CreatedDate.displayValue");

Is there any parameter we can pass to show user's timezone in dataTable or this is excepted behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) mentions the following

[image]

> The locale set in the Salesforce user preferences determines the default formatting for date and time types. The data table supports the date object and dates provided as ISO8601 formatted strings.

This sounds like it should work. But, like you noted, it does use **the computer's time zone setting** to reflect the conversion of the datetime versus the *Salesforce user settings*.

I agree that the datatable doc isn't clear, but if you dig deeper you'll see the behavior is listed under [lightning-formatted-date-time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example) functions (which is used by datatable).

[image]

That's much clearer and matches the behavior of the component. It also shows there is a way to set the timezone to override this behavior.

Within the `lightning-datatable` doc, you can see there is a `typeAttribute` for `timeZone` that will help you achieve what you want (using @POZ's suggestion in combo).

[image]

```
<!-- get user selected timezone on user profile -->
import TIME_ZONE  from '@salesforce/i18n/timeZone';


{
        label: 'LastModifiedDate', 
        fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate', 
        type: 'date', 
        typeAttributes:{
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            timeZone: TIME_ZONE <!-- set the timezone in the datetime column -->
        }
}
```

Comment: I agree this should work.

Comment: Simple search of documentation always work. :facepalm: Thanks @kris

Answer (score 0):

There's no attribute that allows to change the timezone on the datable component.

If you really need to adjust the time, you'll have to fetch the user's timezone as defined in Salesforce with the [i18n wire](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_i18n) then adjust the `data.fields.CreatedDate.value` with some JS.

```js
import TIMEZONE from '@salesforce/i18n/timezone';
```

That being said, I would expect the `getRecord` adapter to return time already set in the right timezone for the user...

Answer (score 0):

**Another Approach Could be**

*gettimeZone Apex class function that will return the string 'users timezone' and 'v.timeZone' is an attribute of the component*

**Apex Class function:**

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static string getTimeZone()
{
  String timeZone = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID();
  // timeZone = 'test';
  return timeZone;
}
```

**Component Helper function**

```
fetchSAHelper : function(component, event, helper) 
{
var action1 = component.get("c.getTimeZone");
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var timeZoneTmp = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.timeZone',response.getReturnValue());
                const actions = [
                    { label: 'View', name: 'view' }
                ];
                component.set('v.mycolumns', [
                    {label: 'Appointment Number', fieldName: 'AppointmentNumber', type: 'text'},
                    {label: 'Start Time', fieldName: 'SchedStartTime',  type: 'date', typeAttributes: {  
                        day: 'numeric',  
                        month: 'short',  
                        hour: '2-digit',  
                        minute: '2-digit',  
                        second: '2-digit',   
                        hour12: true,
                        timeZone: component.get('v.timeZone')}}, 
                    {label: 'End Time', fieldName: 'SchedEndTime', type: 'date', typeAttributes: {  
                        day: 'numeric',  
                        month: 'short',  
                        hour: '2-digit',  
                        minute: '2-digit',  
                        second: '2-digit',  
                        hour12: true,timeZone:  component.get('v.timeZone')}}, 
                    {type:  'button',typeAttributes:{
                        iconName: 'utility:preview',
                        label: 'View', 
                        name: 'viewRecord', 
                        title: 'viewTitle', 
                        disabled: false, 
                        value: 'view'
                    }
                    }
                    
                ]);
                var strn=component.get("v.recordId");
                var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize").toString();
                var pageNumber = component.get("v.pageNumber").toString();
                var action2 = component.get("c.fetchAppointments");
                action2.setParams({
                    recordId : strn,
                    pageSize : pageSize,
                    pageNumber : pageNumber
                });
                action2.setCallback(this, function(response){
                    var state = response.getState();
                    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                        component.set("v.apptList", response.getReturnValue());
                        var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
                        if(resultData.length < component.get("v.pageSize")){
                            component.set("v.isLastPage", true);
                        } else{
                            component.set("v.isLastPage", false);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(action2);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);  
  }
})
```